# Not able to use multiple returns with SetupSequence of NUnit Mock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, moq, nunit-3.0

I am writing unit test cases where I have to return multiple responses based on the required parameters. When I tried the below code it worked fine.

```
_mockClient.SetupSequence(c => c.HttpGet(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>()))
     .Returns(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(_bucketResponseJson) })
     .Returns(new HttpResponseMessage());
```

But when my response is dependent on passed parameters, I am using the following code with a lambda expression.

```
 _mockClient.SetupSequence(c => c.HttpGet(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, string>>()))
                 .Returns(((string url, Dictionary<string, string> headers) =>
                 {
                     return _objectStoreCache[headers[HeaderValue]] as HttpResponseMessage;
                 })).Returns(new HttpResponseMessage());
```

which gives me compile error:

> "Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' because it is not a delegate
>   type"

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do in the setup cannot be done as `ISetupSequentialResult<TResult>` does not allow lambda expressions but rather concrete values to be passed to the `Returns` method. There are also no extension methods that allow that functionality.

```
public interface ISetupSequentialResult<TResult> {
    //... 

    // Summary:
    //     Returns value
    ISetupSequentialResult<TResult> Returns(TResult value);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Do you want me to implement above interface?

Comment: No. That interface is what is returned from `SetupSequence`. Was just showing that the Returns method would not allow for delegate.